Unique item per entity
I want to get the information per Name.
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'],
              'Pair':['b','c','d','e','b','f','d','g'],
              'List 1':['1,2','2,3,4',np.nan,'5',np.nan,'1,2,3','3,6','5,4'],
              'List 2':['1,2,3',',3,4','3','4,5',np.nan,'1,3','1,3,6','5,4']})



For output, I want to split 'Pair' and 'List 1' and 'List 2' into digits and join them.

'Unique Pair': group by each name and get all unique letters. Append them together in a sorted manner.

'Unique Item': group by each name and split it and drop NA and join all unique letters and sort letters.

'All Item': the only difference is that it does not join unique letters but all letters appeared and sort letters. For example, there are two '2' for name A, so it appears twice.


out=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A','B'],
                  'Unique Pair':['b,c,d,e','b,d,f,g'],
                  'Unique List 1 Item':['1,2,3,4,5','1,2,3,4,5,6'],
                  'All List 1 Item':['1,2,2,3,4,5','1,2,3,3,4,5,6'],
                  'Unique List 2 Item':['1,2,3,4,5','1,3,4,5,6'],
                  'All List 2 Item':['1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5','1,1,3,3,4,5,6']
             })


I have tried this but I don't know how to append all items together.
df.groupby('Name')['List'].fillna('NA').apply(lambda x: x.split(','))

My raw dataset has more than 500,000,000 rows, so I am looking for an efficient solution.

You should be using join(), not split().

"The input and output should be self-explanatory" -- things rarely are. The result is an inexact closure as a duplicate. E.g. "List" has '1,2' and '2,3,4' as values. Looks like you want to split those as digits, drop  np.nan, and apply join to all sorted split values as well as the unique sorted set. If so, it does not help that out contains incorrect values: 'Unique Pair' for 'A' is wrong (should be: 'b,c,d,e'). 'All Item', IIUC, is wrong for both. Please [edit] your Q to fix out and explain the desired logic properly. @Barmar: I think this is why OP was using split.

@ouroboros1 I didn't see those. I don't see how it's supposed to work after splitting those up, because there will be too many values in the List column.

I also don't see how the result comes from that input. Where does 1,1,2,2,3,4,5 come from?

@Barmar: no, exactly; it's unclear. So, my guess is that OP sort of means: ','.join(['1,2','2,3,4','5']) -> '1,2,2,3,4,5' (for 'A') and that the double 1 is a typo. Similar for 'B', but there you see that the join is apparently sorted ('A' values already happen to be sorted, of course). And then the unique variant based on these sorted values.

Sorry for the confusion I have editted the questions.

@Derek: thank you for the edits. As for 'Unique Pair', it's now unclear why the requested aggregation has become "group by each name and split it and drop NA and join all unique letters and sort letters". In your example, column 'Pair' has no values to split and no NaN values to drop. If this is necessary for your actual dataset, it will be useful if you again update the sample df to reflect that need. And of course update out as well. E.g., in my answer the 1st option can be adjusted easily. For the 2nd one, that's more difficult.

Hi! Thanks again for the comment. I editted the questions per your comments.

Here's one approach with df.groupby:
out = df.groupby('Name', as_index=False).agg(
    **{
       'Unique Pair': ('Pair', lambda x: 
           ','.join(np.unique(x))
                       ),
       'Unique Item': ('List', lambda x: ','.join(
           np.unique(x.dropna().str.split(',').explode()))
           ),
       'All Item': ('List', lambda x: ','.join(
           x.dropna().str.split(',').explode().sort_values())
           )
    })

Output:
  Name Unique Pair  Unique Item       All Item
0    A     b,c,d,e    1,2,3,4,5    1,2,2,3,4,5
1    B     b,d,f,g  1,2,3,4,5,6  1,2,3,3,4,5,6

Explanation
Use groupby.agg:

for 'Unique Pair' use str.join after applying np.unique, which returns sorted unique elements.
for 'Unique Item' drop NaN values with Series.dropna, apply Series.str.split and Series.explode. Pass result to np.unique and use str.join.
for 'All Item', do the same, but after explode, chain Series.sort_values and then use str.join.

On the use of named aggregations, see here.

To avoid repetition of x.dropna().str.split(',').explode() (which is expensive) for both 'Unique Item' and 'All Item', you can also adjust your df before starting the groupby aggregations. E.g., do something like this:
df = (df.assign(List=df['List'].dropna().str.split(','))
      .explode('List', ignore_index=True)
      )

out2 = df.groupby('Name', as_index=False).agg(
    **{
       'Unique Pair': ('Pair', lambda x: ','.join(np.unique(x))),
       'Unique Item': ('List', lambda x: ','.join(np.unique(x.dropna()))),
       'All Item': ('List', lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().sort_values()))
    })

Output:
out2.equals(out)
# True

If performance is important, and you are working with a large dataset, this will probably be faster.

Thanks for your answer! Could you please tale a look at my editted question, how could I potentially leverage your solution 2 to gain more efficiency?
